# Event loop blocked while calling this promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, canvas, fs

Something is blocking my event loop in node when i call the following promise. Everything looks to be done ASYNC so i don't understand..

Note: i removed unnecessary part of the code for you convenience.

```
function updateImage() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


            fs.readFile('/*...*/ (err, imgSrc) {

                Canvas.createCanvas(/*...*/);

                 for(/*...*/) {
                      g.fillStyle = palette[p.c];
                      g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 1, 1);
                 }


                fs.writeFile('/*...*/ (err) => {


                        DB.query("UPDATE /*...*/ function (e, r, f) {

                                resolve();

                        });

                    })/*...catch*/

                })/*...catch*/

            })/*...catch*/

        })/*...catch*/
    });
}


updateImage().then(() => { /*...*/
```

When i call updateImage() like that, it block my loop event. 
I have socket io running aside this in the same script and it throttle until this function is done..

Does there is a way or a package allowing to track sync calls ?

Comment: Although you've wrapped it in a promise `Canvas.createCanvas` and the for-loop will be executed synchronously. I recommed you read https://snyk.io/blog/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io/

Comment: so maybe i should run 2 nodejs and send the data to the second one, so i can execute updateImage() on a different one and don't block the main one ?